# Can I add my own executables or batch scripts to the boot recovery command prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, executable, boot, recovery

when you boot into windows and screw around with the F-Keys until you get to the repair menu, there is an option to run a command prompt. However, I cannot access any of the files on my PC from that command prompt. Is there any way for me to access them or add my own? Thank you a ton.
[The cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpa2W.jpg)

Comment: You could access other files, just `cd` yourself to other drives(you're defaulted to drive`X`)

Comment: I think I tried that, But ill give it another try, thank you.

Comment: It's ok. Sometimes weird things happen: `c` drive appears as drive `e` on my recovery cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could access other files, just cd yourself to other drives(you're
>   defaulted to driveX) – SteveFest

Perfect!